# How to set Compress-Options for WebP in Android

Tags: android, bitmap, webp

I try to use the [Bitmap.compress](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress%28android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream%29) method from Android's native bitmap. Since API 14, [CompressFormat.WEBP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.CompressFormat.html) is a supported format for this method.
However, no matter what quality value I set, even 100, it always seems to be compressed lossy.  Is there any way to force loosless WEBP Compression and also have control if you want to store alpha?